# Console error 403 (Forbidden) when trying to include on Mac Apache

Tags: macos, apache

I cant seem to include anything on my built in Apache for Mac when building pages.

I have a project which has a standard stylesheet link and a js script link and both of theese are not loading for me when working on my built in Apache on MAC.

I see errors 403 (Forbidden) on the console for the page.

To my understanding this is a permission issue of some sort. Can anyone advise how to solve?

Comment: Often faced with a similar problem. Сheck that apache2 user have access to your project folder. Apache user must have acces for reading root colder.

Comment: Put in your question your apache2 config: located here /etc/apache2/httpd.conf, after it put your virtualhost config file and make ls -ld /path/to/your_public_html_direcory